# Django database and information history

Tags: python, database, django, web, django-models

I am using Django framework to build a website with the ability to record user information and its history of modification. As what i can image, i can use a Django self-defined app to record the information history. This self-defined app would contain classes with information stored in dictionary.

```
    Class Information(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User)

        info = {'date': value}

    def create_information(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Information.objects.create(user=instance)
    post_save.connect(create_control_information, sender=User)
```

Can any one tell me if there is some other better way to record information in Django web developing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, Because You'll want to access your user's history directly from a User instance, use django's [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) field.

When doing so, accessing a users history will look something like this:

```
my_user.information_set.all()
```

You can change the name the user's history from 'information_set' to, for example, 'history', by specifying related_name argument in the ForeignKey constructor, like so:

```
Class Information(models.Model):
     ...
     user=models.ForeignKey(related_name='history')
```

And now to access a user's history, you can write:

```
my_user.history.all()
```

---

Also, Please notice that in your current design, the info won't be stored in the database.
I assume that most of the history data you want to store will have the same structure. Consider using a field for each piece of info you want to keep in your history. For example, for keeping the date and time of the action, use [DateTimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield)